# How to pass multiple Column values in a single query And get the data if atleast one column value is matched?

Tags: php, mysql

Table

```
c1  c2   c3   c4
-----------------
1   2    3    4
----------------
2   2    4    3
---------------
3   3    4    2
-------------------
```

Here i want to pass mutiple coumnn values in single query if at least one value is selected and there is a chance of selecting multiple values.

Here is My Html code.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="col1[]" value="1">1
<input type="checkbox" name="col1[]" value="2">2
<input type="checkbox" name="col1[]" value="3">3 
<input type="checkbox" name="col2[]" value="1">1
<input type="checkbox" name="col2[]" value="2">2
<input type="checkbox" name="col2[]" value="4">4
<input type="checkbox" name="col3[]" value="1">1
<input type="checkbox" name="col3[]" value="2">2
<input type="checkbox" name="col3[]" value="3">3
<input type="checkbox" name="col4[]" value="1">1
<input type="checkbox" name="col4[]" value="2">2
<input type="checkbox" name="col4[]" value="3">3
```

### PHP Code

```
$r1= $_POST['col1'];
$r2 = $_POST['col2'];
$r3 = $_POST['col3'];
$r4 = $_POST['col4'];

foreach($resistor as $index => $value)
{
    $cr1 = $r1[$index];
    $cr2 = $r2[$index];
    $cr3 = $r3[$index];
    $cr4 = $r4[$index];
}
$stmt = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE t1=? AND t2=? AND t3=? AND t4=? ORDER BY tid ASC";
$sql = $dbConnection->prepare($stmt);
$sql->execute(array($cr1,$cr2,$cr3,$cr4));
```

This is my code.
please any one help me to solve this issue.Iam new to php.

Comment: use `or` not `and` idk ... plus the column names are wrong, no ?

Comment: tried using Or also but it wont works

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` and you'll see where you're going wrong

Comment: how is $rn even an array? where n is 1 to 4. Even it is worked, you are working against user-supplied values not cleansed of sql-injection. It is highly likely you are never getting inside the foreach loop, so the $crn are all blank